# Auto login to website using Google Apps Script

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script, autologin

I want to auto-login on the website https://www.shiftboard.com/log-in/ using Google apps script.
Here is my google apps script code

```
function login() {
  var payload =
  {
     "auth_user" : "",
     "auth_password" : "",
  };
  var options =
  {
     "method" : "post",
     "payload" : payload,
     "followRedirects" : false
  };
  var login = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.shiftboard.com/log-in/" , options);
  var sessionDetails = login.getAllHeaders()
  Logger.log(sessionDetails)
}
```

In logger, Output is like that

### [image]

I did not get any cookies

Answer (score 0):

If you look at login form's `form` tag in the HTML code of `https://www.shiftboard.com/log-in/`, you can see that it actually submits to `/servola/auth.cgi`.

The form tag:

```
<form class="login-form" method="post" action="/servola/auth.cgi">
```

This means that `fetch("https://www.shiftboard.com/log-in/" , options)` should be changed to `fetch("https://www.shiftboard.com/servola/auth.cgi" , options)`.

I assume you are aware, but there is a [documented API for Shiftboard](https://www.shiftdata.com/).